# junit complete differences between expected and actual

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I am developing unit tests using Junit on Intelij Idea. When a test fails, it just logs the hash code of expected and actual object and i should find the differences either with comparing their fields or tracing equals method in debug mode which would be much exhausting if the equals and hashcode been generated by commons single line builder (then i should replace them with dummy chain of equals to just find the field caused the problem).

So is there any tool or something (i have no idea) to print complete differences in object structure (at least in first level without expanding inner objects)?

Comment: please edit your question and add a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows your problem

Comment: Tool?   No, you just need to know how to write Java.  Wait til 2071?  Is advanced AI needed here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logging the hash code tells me that you didn't override the toString method in the class.  You probably didn't override equals or hashCode, either.

You need to read ["Effective Java" chapter 3](http://www.csd.uoc.gr/~hy252/project_old/Chapter3.pdf).

Comment: I have overridden equals and hashCode, but missed the toString!!, thanks